# When is reference-counting needed in a single threaded application that doesn't model circular data structures?

Tags: rust, reference-counting

Rust can handle reference counting very elegantly with [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html). It seems many members of the community prefer not to use this and instead use the ownership/borrowing semantics of the language. This results in simpler programs to write, but aside from circular references is it **ever** necessary?

Clearly across threads things get more complex, so to simplify what I'm trying to learn, *"in a single threaded application is reference-counting ever required except as a write-time optimization?"* Is this an anti-pattern at the higher levels of Rust skill?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67747657/why-do-we-need-rct-when-immutable-references-can-do-the-job) answer the question?

Comment: @user2722968 I love your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67750386/68587) in that question, yet I find this question easier to understand and more relatable. I wish we could marry the two.

Answer (score 7):

I think that @kmdreko is basically correct, but an example that's harder to model without `Rc` would be something like filtering queries with "heavy" data, down into multiple owners.  Basically, any time you deal with a "set" into multiple other filtered sets, where the filters may overlap.

For example, if you gathered 1000 images, and you invoked OpenCV (or whatever) to find in the original set which images had birds, and which images had a tree in them, it's plausible that the result sets overlap.  So if you don't use `Rc` (or similar), you're either copying these potentially huge images (probably not wanted) or keeping references to them.  OK, but then you can't ever free the original set of images, as it's what owns the images that the result sets are referencing.  And while there are workarounds to that (only preserve an image when one or more filter says to), then that leads to deeply integrating potentially separate parts of your program because of the memory model you use.  Or just use `Rc` and it's "accessible" by others easily, and whatever brought it in can be "done" with the set and free everything not referenced, while the parts of the set still used are still preserved.

I agree that `Rc` and related can be over-used.  I encounter that all the freaking time in C++ and people throwing `shared_ptr` all over the place and think they're "good" at that point (until the application or DLL shuts down, and the calls of "why is my application crashing on exit all the time??" start coming).  That said, even single-threaded, sometimes ownership needs to be shared, so it can be passed on to an unknown number of consumers for later.

Like with most tools, there are ways to work around certain parts, but that may cause more pain instead.

Comment: See the [im](https://crates.io/crates/im) crate for a good example of this.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `Rc` when you need *shared ownership*. Using `Arc` is no different, but perhaps its more common since standard threading mechanisms like `std::thread::spawn` require ownership.

You would still use `Rc` in single-threaded environments if your data is more graph-like (which could have circular dependencies but doesn't have to). In such cases, you cannot use basic references. You *could* represent graph-like relationships in a normalized fashion and use indexes or ids in lieu of references, but that may not always be favorable or possible. Of course, if you're using `Rc` when a structure could be represented hierarchically, using `Rc` would be unnecessary.

In addition, there's many reasons why a external function or structure would require a generic type or function to be `'static`. In those situations, either moving, `clone()`-ing or sharing (with `Rc`) is the solution.

I wouldn't say `Rc` itself an anti-pattern, its simply another tool, but there are sometimes ways to avoid it that would result in clearer relationships and/or better performance. I often see `Rc` used liberally by Rust newcomers who haven't fully grasped the borrow-checker.